# Rounded corners in a card view won't work at the bottom of image with a text view

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-cardview

I am trying to get a card view so that I get a rounded corners image with a text under it but the thing is, when I add the text, since they are both inside of the rounded corners card view, the image is not rounded at the bottom (which is what I need). How would I accomplish that?

This is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="16dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_news"
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/background_shape"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/news_title"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

The image (I need the bottom corners of the image also rounded):
[image]

Comment: The answer you marked as correct is not optimal, you should give it a second thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put this code in your `"@drawable/background_shape"`. Just tried it and it all working fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp" android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: If they already used `cardview` and also give a radius so why do we need to create a separate drawable ?

Comment: This answer is dirty and don't address the real problem. The textview View space usage is the problem.

Comment: @MohakShah that happens because we set corner radius only for card element and so we get what we wanted - card corners are cut as we described in XML. But that corner radius doesn't apply to the child of the card view. Top corners of the ImageView cutted because they overlap parent top corners. Same with TextView at the bottom. But we didn't change corner behavior on ImageView. There is no reason why the bottom corners of the ImageView should be cutted in the layout above.

Comment: in the end this did not work in the actual running of the app

Comment: You also need to change `android:src="@drawable/background_shape"` to `android:background="@drawable/background_shape"`. As far as I understand - you change src as soon as image from server ready, so corners you set in the background_shape doesn't apply anymore

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `TextView` is overlaying the card radius. To fix that add padding to the text view or to the card and that should solve it.

The answer marked as correct, is not clean: Adds an unnecessary drawable, the card view already has a corner radius property, making the child implement round corners as well defeat the purpose of such attribute.

Also, try to use material card view: `<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView/>`. You might not needed it now but it has more customizations.

Comment: what type of padding? top padding does not help

Comment: There are 5 padding attributes, you have only tried 1. There is 1 general `android:padding`, and one specific for each direction, why don't you start with that one and then narrow it down? Why top, if your problem is on the left bottom corner and the right bottom corner?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a circular image in that case you need to add only ImageView inside CardView, and which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
         android:layout_width="300dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_margin="16dp"
         app:cardCornerRadius="16dp">

         <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_news"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:src="@drawable/background_shape"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

     </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

     <TextView
          android:id="@+id/tv_title"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/news_title"
          android:textColor="@color/black"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
          android:textAlignment="center"
          android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```